# Need help in understanding how to find an elementary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I read this chapter in my book and thought I understood it, but I don't.  I tried working a problem to test my understanding and I just don't know how to get started.

Given the following matrices:

$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & -3 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \\ -1 & 2 & 0
 \\ \end{bmatrix}$
$B=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 & -3
 \\ \end{bmatrix}$

Find an elementary matrix $E$ such that $EA = B$

What I think I understand... a matrix is elementary when a single row operation forms an $I_n$ matrix.  I don't understand how this applies though.  Please help!

Comment: Was $B$ given or does it only denote an arbitrary matrix?

Comment: @ZoltanZimboras, yes, $B$ was given, my mistake.  I'll include it now.

Comment: What do you mean by 'how this applies'?

Comment: @GeorgeTomlinson if I have an identity matrix, I don't understand how a single row operation on my identity matrix corresponds to the given matrix.  If that makes any sense whatsoever.

Comment: Hopefully you can see from the question, the answer below from Zoltan Zimboras and the comments on it that the single row operation of swapping R1 and R3 of I corresponds to the given matrix (assuming you mean A) in that doing so yields the matrix E such that EA = B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unique matrix that satisfies $EA = B$ is the matrix that "swaps" the 
first and third rows. It is given as

$$E=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0
 \\ \end{bmatrix}.$$

Edit: 
Due to a question in the comments, here comes a bit longer explanation.

(1) The rows of matrix $B$ and $A$ are the same, except for the fact that we have to swap 
the first and the third row.

(2) $E$, defined above, is the special matrix that swaps the first and third rows of any $3 \times 3$ matrix $O$ when multiplied by it from the left. This can, for example, be seen by simple matrix multiplication

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0
 \\ \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} p_1 & p_2 & p_3 \\ q_1 & q_2 & q_3 \\ r_1 & r_2 & r_3
 \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} r_1 & r_2 & r_3 \\ q_1 & q_2 & q_3 \\ p_1 & p_2 & p_3
 \\ \end{bmatrix}. $$

Hence, as a particular case, we also have $EA=B$. (Moreover, since $A$ and $B$ are non-singular matrices, the solution to the matrix equation $XA=B$ is unique: $X=BA^{-1}$,
calculating this we would again get $X=E$.)

(3) Elementary matrices (see definition [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix)) differs from the identity matrix by one single elementary row operation. After swapping the first and third row of $E$ (which is an elementary row operation) we arrive to matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
 \\ \end{bmatrix},$$

which is exactly the identity matrix. Hence $E$ is an elementary matrix.

Comment: And what is the single row operation that transforms it into the identity, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @GeorgeTomlinson swapping the first and third row of $E$ yields the identity.

Didn't leave much work for the OP to do, mind you, but there it is.

Comment: @GeorgeTomlinson : I guess the question is settled now :).

Comment: I don't 'see' how you got to this.  Would you mind elaborating just a little more?  What does this have to do with the identity matrix and why do we need to do this?

Comment: @inquisitor I can expand the explanation of my answer, if you wish.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'd really appreciate that.

Comment: I think I understand it now.  Given the identity matrix, if I multiply the original matrix by the identity I will get the given matrix.  However, if I modify the identity and multiply the given matrix by the modified identity, I will get the modified matrix $B$ in this example.

Comment: @inquisitor Correct! (As also George Tomlinson noted.) I anyway added a few more explanatory lines to the answer.

Comment: Correct, although your wording could be improved (I hope you don't mind me saying that). I wouldn't say 'given the identity matrix'. It is of course true that IA=A. It's also true that EA=B.